# How to run cucumber appium test cases on azure(VSTS) devops pipeline

Tags: user-interface, azure-devops, automated-tests, appium, cucumberjs

I'm planning to run android and ios UI automation(cucumber+ appium) tests in azure release pipeline. Need help

Answer (score 0):

> How to run cucumber appium test cases on azure(VSTS) devops pipeline

AFAIK, there is a test automation service [App Center Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/), which service for native and hybrid mobile applications and it support for several popular test frameworks, like:

[image]

Besides, the App Center Test task for Azure Pipelines lets you run your test suites in App Center Test. You can use Appium, XCUItest, Espresso, and Xamarin.UITest frameworks.

For the details info, you can check the document [Using Azure DevOps for UI Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/vsts-plugin).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where did you find that screenshot (mainly cucumber) page? Because, as I can see, there is no support

Comment: @BharatChavan, Check the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/supported-frameworks

Comment: Is there any way we can run tests without using App center?

Comment: This is a terrible answer @LeoLiu-MSFT. It answers by telling people you have to use and pay for yet another service which doesn't even support .NET developers... The question is how to run Appium in Azure Pipelines... not how to integrate with a 3rd part service such as App Center.